# Python string building from array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got an array of strings of the form `['this', 'that']`.

I need to get a string at the end that says:

```
('this', 'that')
```

I know I can get the comma in with .join(), how can I get the quotes around each item in the most elegant way?

Comment: Just use `repr`: `repr(tuple(array))`

Comment: That gives the right answer but with square brackets; is there an easy to swap them to round ones? (it's for an SQL query)

Comment: Strange, `repr(tuple(array))` gives me round brackets just fine.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be doing this for an SQL query? In particular, haveyou properly escaped the values of the list so that you're not exposing your app to SQL injection attacks?

Comment: My mistake, I left out the tuple()! Thank you, that works perfectly, and is wonderfully elegant! :). No need worry about SQL injection, this is for personal data analysis, not a public facing application.

Comment: Okay, just checking :-) Although even then I would argue that doing proper escaping is helpful; no one ever got hurt by it, and sooner or later your data will have a quote or some such, or worse, you may copy that little function to a real application in a year's time and you forgot that you didn't bother to escape stuff ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like *vaultah* said use `repr()` which is used to compute the string representation of an object.

For example,

if `array = ['this', 'that', 'is', 'the', 'input']`

then `array = repr(tuple(array))`

will result in: `('this', 'that', 'is', 'the', 'input')`